# Aws amplify nextjs app build failed without error log

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy app to AWS Amplify and it seems to be built in logs but it's not and it says build failed while not logging cuz in frontend console it says "Terminating logging". I have no idea what's going on here. Anyone can possibly know why is this happening?

last few lines of logs:

```
                               + First Load JS shared by all       350 kB
                                 ├ chunks/framework.2f6124.js      42.4 kB
                                 ├ chunks/main.09a552.js           21.1 kB
                                 ├ chunks/pages/_app.f62963.js     286 kB
                                 ├ chunks/webpack.6d72c6.js        851 B
                                 └ css/5038894fdc8e74a0a872.css    23.2 kB
2021-07-19T20:33:49.641Z [INFO]: λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
                                 ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
                                 ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
                                 (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
2021-07-19T20:33:49.837Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
Terminating logging...
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when building the app locally?

Comment: Not really, at the beginning locally it was throwing some exit status 1 caused by one empty routing file, but I initilized it with react stateless component template and it built normally, but locally I have no idea if it should start automatically after building, if it should then it is not, I have to execute npm run start after building to start app.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not really, it just started work when I changed NextJS version from 10.x to 11.